# running javascript on site load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having a spot of difficulty with a java/css tabbed menu system. I've had the menus up and running for some time but I've recently tried adding a new charting system to one of the pages and I've been finding it difficult to get it to display properly.

I've traced it down to a css entry that's needed in order to prevent all of the tabbed content from being displayed until you hover over each tab. CSS is as below:

```
div.tabscontainer div.curvedContainer .tabcontent{
display:none;
padding:20px;
font-size:12px;
font-family: "CenturyGothicRegular", "Century Gothic", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

As said, the display:none prevents all of the content from being displayed until you hover over one of the tabs. However that same display:none prevents my charting script from drawing the chart properly. If I comment the display:none out, then the chart is drawn correctly but all of the tabbed content is displayed on page load. Sort of Catch 22.

However, if I do comment out the display:none and then hover over any of the menu tabs, the following javascript runs and all the respective content is correctly hidden or displayed as required:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs .tab[id^=tab_menu]").hover(function() {
        var curMenu=$(this);
        $(".tabs .tab[id^=tab_menu]").removeClass("selected");
        curMenu.addClass("selected");

        var index=curMenu.attr("id").split("tab_menu_")[1];
        $(".curvedContainer .tabcontent").css("display","none");
        $(".curvedContainer #tab_content_"+index).css("display","block");
    });
});
</script>
```

I can sort of understand what the script is doing in a psuedo-code sort of way, it's changing the property of the the tab itself (add/remove "selected class") to allow it to appear "highlighted" while changing the property of the content container (add/remove display:none or block) to either hide or show the content of each tab as applicable.

My thinking, now, is that if I add a modified version of the above script to run on page load and automatically select the first tab, then I can remove the global display:none from the CSS and just allow the javascript to sort it out.

This, finally, leads to my question. I am still new to javascript and I'm trying to work out how I'd modify the above code to reflect my need for it to automatically select a given menu (tab_menu_50) on page load, while still allowing the user to hover over any tab.

Any pointers that you can give are gladly accepted and I apologise in advance if nothing of the above makes any sense at all! (Although, if you could tell me I've got it completely wrong, I'd be grateful of that too!)

Jonathan

Have tried to remove all the content but still give an idea of the site structure, hope this helps in finding an answer. There may be some errant  tags but that's just because of the hack job I've just done to allow me to post some html on here...

```
<html>
<head>

# Below script enables tab switch on mouseover

<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tabs .tab[id^=tab_menu]").hover(function() {
    var curMenu=$(this);
    $(".tabs .tab[id^=tab_menu]").removeClass("selected");
    curMenu.addClass("selected");

    var index=curMenu.attr("id").split("tab_menu_")[1];
    $(".curvedContainer .tabcontent").css("display","none");
    $(".curvedContainer #tab_content_"+index).css("display","block");
});
});
</script>

# Below script draws the chart

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('.charttable').visualize({type: 'line'});
    });
</script>


<style>


# Below style sheet contains the problematic entry of display:none

div.tabscontainer div.curvedContainer .tabcontent{
display:none;
padding:20px;
font-size:12px;
font-family: "CenturyGothicRegular", "Century Gothic", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


</head>

<body>


<div class="tabscontainer">
    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="tab first selected" id="tab_menu_50">
            <div class="link">Home</div>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab" id="tab_menu_150">
            <div class="link">Screen2</div>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab last" id="tab_menu_250">
            <div class="link">Screen3</div>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="curvedContainer">
        <div class="tabcontent" id="tab_content_50">
        </div>
        <div class="tabcontent" id="tab_content_150">
        </div>
        <div class="tabcontent" id="tab_content_250">
<table class="charttable">
    <caption>Visits from August 16 to August 21</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th scope="col">chartlabel1</th>
        <th scope="col">chartlabel2</th>
        <th scope="col">chartlabel3</th>
        <th scope="col">chartlabel4</th>
        <th scope="col">chartlabel5</th>
        <th scope="col">chartlabel6</th>
        <th scope="col">chartlabel7</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">SuiteA</th>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>49</td>
        <td>52</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>44</td>
        <td>57</td>
        <td>61</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">SuiteB</th>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">SuiteC</th>
        <td>73</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>74</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>73</td>
        <td>75</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say `automatically select the first tab`, what constitutes "selecting the first tab"?

Comment: It would help if you can post some `HTML` too..

Comment: Thank for replies guys - AdamD - sorry, I mean automatically selecting the tab as though the user had hovered over it. Will try and post some HTML now...

Comment: Hi Adrian, I've added some html as promised...

Comment: Have found the problem and, unsurprisingly, it was my own stupidity. It turns out that if you want the chart to draw first you should probably tell the page to execute the javascript for drawing the chart first. Look at above html code to see what I mean and comence mocking. Thanks for everybody's help none the less as it's still helped me with the fix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just trigger the event on DOM ready, *after* the hover event is bound in your example code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#desiredTab').trigger('mouseover');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LC2un/

Comment: Nice one, I can now drop the display:none but it still appears to activate too quickly and prevent the chart from drawing...? Still trying though...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, you probably want to use visiblity:hidden instead of display:none.

If you set the display:none, then certain calculations can't be done on those nodes unless the dimensions are explicitly coded in; calculated dimensions (nodes that don't have a fixed width or height can't be calculated ni a reliable manner across all browsers).

Setting a node to visibility:hidden essentially sets its opacity to 0, while leaving it and its dimensions within the document.

Try replacing display: none; with visiblity: hidden

Hopefully should work.  If it doesn't, you can also try setting its visibility by using jquery's .hide() method on document load..

```
$("div.tabscontainer div.curvedContainer .tabcontent").hide()
```

Comment: This allows me to remove the display:none but it still stops the chart from drawing properly..? Still could be useful and I'm trying different implimentations as we speak, cheers!